# Select first instance of a button in a table row based on cell content by XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Good Day Everyone!   I am Struggling with clicking on a button in the first cell if the fourth cell text = zero.  I am trying to iterate through the table rows until I come across `[td[1][button[text() = 'Review']` and `td[4][a[text() = '0']`

Code as follows, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
IWebElement baseTable = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='summaryGrid']/table/tbody"));
ICollection<IWebElement> rows = baseTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    bool x = row.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[td[1][button[text() = 'Review']] and td[4][a[text() = '0']]]")).Displayed;

    if (x == true)
    {
        row.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[td[1][button[text() = 'Review']] and td[4][a[text() = '0']]]//button[0]")).Click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your  html and point  at the element you're trying to click at. The predicates in xpaths are wrong. You must put absolute or relative path before 'td's

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ please.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath should give you all the first buttons in the first cells by the conditions you gave

```
//tr/td[1][/button[text() = 'Review'] and /td[4]/a[text() = '0']]/button[1]
```

Then you could iterate through it and click() on every element.

Sorry, I'm not a C# guy, so use it as an outline for a solution

```
ICollection<IWebElement> buttons = baseTable.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr/td[1][/button[text() = 'Review'] and /td[4]/a[text() = '0']]/button[1]"));
foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    button.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the forth `<td>` element with text as **Review** in first cell in-case the fourth `<td>` element's text is **0** you can use the following code block :

```
IWebElement forthRowElement = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='summaryGrid']/table/tbody//tr//following-sibling::td[4]"));
if (forthRow.Text == '0')
{
    forthRow.FindElement(By.XPath("//self::td//preceding::td[3]")).Click();
}
```